# running gcc failed: exit status 1 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXxf86vm collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: linux, go, gcc, fyne

I make the command `go run mаіn.go` but after that an error of such a plan occurs.

## command-line-arguments

/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
your text`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find  -lXxf86vm
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Compilation via gcc ends with nothing. The simplest program through Go + fyne "Hello World" does not open. Please help with this on Linux mint.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don’t have the required development headers installed. Some Linux distros make this a little opaque… so we wrote this doc: https://developer.fyne.io/started/